# Django python manage.py collectstatic UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, web, ascii

My problem is the following:
When I'm running `python manage.py collectstatic` inside of my Django-project I'm getting this error:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:302: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
return name == ":memory:" or "mode=memory" in force_text(name)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 151, in handle
message.append(':\n\n     %s\n\n' % destination_path)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I somewhat know, why it occurs but I'm not able to fit it. (Maybe because I didn't want to break any Django files...)

If you need some more Information I'll happily give it to you.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have unicode characters in your filesystem path? Also, what version of Django are you using?

Comment: Could you post the value of STATIC_ROOT/MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: @trinchet `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` MEDIA_ROOT is not set!

Comment: and the BASE_DIR? it could be great if you post the values these vars get when you run your develop server

Answer (score 2):

It works for me export in console.

1º

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

2º

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

check over [django-pipeline/issues](https://github.com/jazzband/django-pipeline/issues/242)